# ADB2C Implementation with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, nuget-package, azure-ad-b2c

I want to implement ADB2C implementation with my cross-platform Xamarin Forms app.
Want latest tutorials to support latest nuget packages.
Old samples not working.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/) from Microsoft?
You can implement ADB2C using [MSAL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/) package.